# Code backup in Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am a newbie to Salesforce Marketing Cloud (SFMC). I am already a developer on the core Salesforce platform and was wondering if there is a way to take the code backup in SFMC like Salesforce. In Salesforce I extract all the metadata using ANT and was wondering if SFMC has something similar.
Any pointers are much appreciated.

Regards,
Sandeep

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent in Marketing Cloud. That is, you can't take a snapshot of account settings, Data Extensions, Automations, Interactions, Emails, Reports, etc and import them into another Business Unit or Account.

You can of course export data from Data Extensions, but I don't believe that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is stale but if you’re looking for SFMCE backups take a look at stashr.io on the app exchange.

[disclaimer] it’s an app that I’ve built with my employer.